# Room - Slow Query in Background

Tags: android, performance, rx-java2, android-room

I'm currently implementing Room to replace my old SQL code, but I'm running into an issue where my query is very slow when running in the background.

For example, I have two identical queries, one that runs on the UI thread, and another that returns a `Single`. I'm using `allowMainThreadQueries()` to test this case.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY `begin` ASC LIMIT $LIMIT")
    fun getUIThreadSchedule(): List<Event>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY `begin` ASC LIMIT $LIMIT")
    fun getSchedule(): Single<List<Event>>
```

Now, when I run both of these and compare the time to give me a result, they are very different.

This will take ~6ms to complete.

```
    val events = database.getUIThreadSchedule()
```

And this will take ~360ms to complete.

```
    database.getSchedule()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                   // elements are now here
                }, {
                    // show an error view
                })
```

I tried using other options, such as `Flowable`, but the result is the same.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of looking into the issue, I found the why this call was taking longer than the blocking call.

When calling `getSchedule()`, the subscribe block is not run right when the query is completed. It has to wait for the UI thread, so if that's blocked in another aspect, it will have to wait.

```
// start query
database.getSchedule()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                   // once ui thread is available, display content
                }, {
                    // ...
                })
```

The reason my UI thread was blocked is because I'm testing on cold start, so my Fragment would created, my query would be fired off, but then it would have to wait for the first frame of the rest of the UI to render before I could handle the `getSchedule()` result.

With the blocking call, it already had the UI thread, so there was no waiting.